# Remove [implementation]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

[implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/implementation) may have > 1000 Questions, but it has < 10 followers. That must be due to its uselessness.

Comment: You have my permission to begin removal.

Comment: Don't you, as a mod, have a tool to remove it all at once?

Comment: [Nope](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250933/how-do-tag-removal-burnination-requests-work).  [See Also](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220200/102937).

Comment: Should I be approving all the implementation removal edits that are now piling up in the queue? They link this post.  Someone is trying to score big.

Comment: @Louis [Please stop editing! You're flooding the queues.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51230/room-for-bjb568-and-louis)

Comment: @Richard I'm going to start rejecting them.

Comment: @bjb568 Gotcha, I'm sorry!

Comment: @RichScriven link was incorrect, the "_question about it_" is actually https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251740/

Comment: The [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/implementation/info) for `[implementation]` now says: ***"This tag is in the process of removal. Please don't use it."***

Answer (score -7):

It is end of 2019, the tag has 1820 questions now (even with the warning attached to it), so it must be useful after all.

And I had to use it just now to tag a question, because there was no better alternative.

So no, the tag *is* useful and should not be removed.

Comment: I have just used a tag. Unfortunately, when typing on a mobile, I don't see any descriptions (and therefore warnings) about tags that I use. I do look up the tags afterwards to see which ones are irrelevant (as words can mean different things in different computing contexts) and edit them out. I wonder if others who still use this tag type their messages on a mobile...

Comment: @Heimdall really? _all_ of them? and it's 1,958 questions and 76 watchers now. :)

Comment: People misusing a tag a lot doesn’t make it useful.