# Should I approve [implementation] tag removal edits piling up in the review queue?

Tags: discussion, tags, review-queues, suggested-edits

There are numerous edits in my review queue that cite [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251723/remove-implementation) as the reason for the edit.

Here's an example

> [image]

In the cited post, there is no accepted answer on whether the tags are actually to be removed, and it is unclear from the short comment stream whether they should be approved or not.

Being that there are over 1000 questions tagged `implementation`, the person that suggested the edit (and others that notice this is going on) stand to continue to score big reputation points if these edits are approved.

Should reviewers go ahead and approve these edits?

Comment: 1000 questions is nothing,if you want rep go for super tags: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41206/should-questions-be-tagged-with-both-a-tag-and-a-sub-tag =)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is either Yes or No.

You should reject such tags edits as 'too minor' if there is more to fix in the post. Suggested edits should fix everything there is to fix, grammar, spelling, formatting, rewording and retagging.

You should accept a tag only edit if there is nothing more to improve in the post.

Now for the mass-retagging of questions itself:
It is better left to users with more than [2K of reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) as their edits don't go into the queue. Or even better 10K-ers: [they have additional functionality to quickly edit tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117624/why-is-inline-tag-editing-not-available-with-retag-privileges).

Keep in mind though that an [edit can bump a post causing it to show up in the active tab or even on the front-page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48579/158100).

**IMPORTANT**
When you start an edit (be it an *inline retag* or a *normal* edit) you should **always** fix everything in the post. That is: if someone else improves the post after your edit, you failed.

Comment: I disagree that mass retagging is better done by 10k users, particularly because I don't think inline tag editing should be used (in general) (and it can certainly be a temptation if it's available). Due to the bumping that occurs, one should fix all issues, regardless of whether or not it goes to the suggested edits review queue.

Comment: @Dukeling Added that to the post...