# Destroy [creation]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/creation) tag is ambiguous. It must go. 'tis not very useful (to put it mildly).

Comment: Those 3 followers will be upset.. :-)  still it has 342 questions tagged

Comment: @rene There's no wiki. No sense of purpose. Those 342 questions are all over the board.

Comment: @ckuhn203 agreed. With a low number of questions I normally start removing the tag by hand but 342 is beyond my will to start a mass-tag-edit

Comment: @rene I'll lend a hand if it seems it has community support. A couple of us could crack through in no time. Beats spending time on facebook.

Comment: Thanks for the offer but it is more wise to have a 2K-er do that. Your edits need to pass the suggested-edit queue. That is good for the rep but no good for mass-retags...

Comment: @rene I see no reason why sub-2K users are discouraged to do such edits. It's not like the queue is ever large.

Comment: If 3 people need to review that post it rather be a good substantial edit. Some posts can be improved for sure but some might only need the tag removed. Those edits are discouraged because it is a waste of the review resources.

Comment: @rene The edit queue is highly-contested by reviewers, so I see no problem.

Comment: @rene I couldn't care about the rep. It's a useless tag.

Comment: @ckuhn203 I say go for it!

Comment: @ckuhn203 Give [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187420/what-is-the-suggested-edit-review-policy-for-tag-only-edits-now) a read and then make sure you improve everything on the post! Let me know were you start

Comment: @rene I'm happy to put the work in, but if you wanted to get your point across, you should have just pointed me [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251742/3198973). I'll keep an eye on the thread and if the community decides to burn it, I'll lend a hand.

Comment: I don't remember all answers I have given... I was desperatly searching at MSE for a canonical post :-)

Comment: I would have liked this question more if the title was "Destroy [creation]" ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber are you going to do *pew pew pew*?

Comment: Awesome edit! :) And yes, @rene. Why did you need to ask???

Comment: I wanted to type *pew pew pew*...

Comment: @rene I no understand *pew* joke.

Comment: @Tshepang I tries to mimick the sound of a gun and is sometimes used in the Tavern on the Meta to request a moderator to delete stuff.

Comment: As a bonus I have [this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/189345/how-is-a-tag-used-in-combination-with-other-tags) that shows how tag is used in combination with other tags. Another good indication the tag was useless.

Comment: I propose a synonym to [intelligent-design].

Comment: I hope it's OK, I mildly edited to bump this to the front page again because I think that it should occur.

Answer (score 6):

I think that we should burn this.

To go through the [criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/343810):

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

Well, it's not a Meta tag, but it's certainly not unambiguous. It has numerous possible meanings.

Creation isn't a real topic - how could someone possibly be an expert in "creation"? What would that even mean?

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Yes, technically.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No, what does "creation" even *mean*? It says absolutely nothing about what you're actually trying to do or what the topic of the post is.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

No, there are numerous possible meanings here.

I think that we should burn this tag.