# Multiple meaning of 'ctools' tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-wiki

I was about to edit wiki page of [ctools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ctools) tag when I found it is used for two different topics:

1. [ctools [Drupal - Chaos tool suite]](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools) = This suite is primarily a set of APIs and tools to improve the developer experience.
2. [ctools [Pentaho - Community Tools]](http://www.webdetails.pt/ctools/) = A set of tools and components, working on top of Pentaho for custom dashboard implementation.

The [ctools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ctools) tag started to be used along with [drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal) tag. But now it is often used along with both [pentaho](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pentaho) and [drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal) tags.

What is the best ways to handle the duplicate usage of [ctools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ctools) tag?

- What come into my mind at first option is to keep [ctools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ctools) for Drupal as the early usage was for Drupal (edit a [ctools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ctools) tag wiki in this way). Create [pentaho-ctools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pentaho-ctools) tag + edit [pentaho-ctools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pentaho-ctools) wiki + re-tag all posts with a combination of [pentaho](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pentaho) [ctools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ctools) to [pentaho](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pentaho) [pentaho-ctools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pentaho-ctools) (tens of posts - not that much).

Is the tag-split the right approach or am I dealing here with insignificant matters?

There is one more thing - I don't have the *Creation privilege*, so I can't create the [pentaho-ctools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pentaho-ctools) tag. Is there any other way of how to do create it?

Comment: [drupal-ctools] and [pentaho-ctools] all the way.

Comment: @mzy do you mind letting users with edit privileges make these edits? Your edits are flooding the review queue

Comment: @Luigi Sorry about that. My fault I did not think about flooding the review queue. All edits (about 50) are done by now.

Comment: It's okay, I did literally [the exact same thing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251723/remove-implementation#comment4430_251723) when I had lower rep.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of just keeping [ctools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ctools) ambiguous, or forcing it to mean the Drupal ctools, I propose we just split it up into [drupal-ctools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-ctools) and [pentaho-ctools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pentaho-ctools).

- We don't need to worry about [ctools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ctools) being ambiguous
- Each tool gets its own tag

There are only 65 questions in [ctools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ctools), so retagging shouldn't take too long. I've gone ahead and created these two tags, if someone can add useful tag wikis that'd be great.